Remaining Packages after a Failed System Update
Ubuntu Update Manager stalled on the upgrade of a package (surfshark VPN). After quite some time, I have killed the entire process and rebooted. I have removed surfshark from my system, but when executing "sudo apt-update" and "upgrade" the system reports that it is up to date, and nothing needs to be installed. However, there were numerous system updates that do not appear to have been installed, since I have kill the process before the end. While Update Manager was stuck, it was displaying "unpacking surfshark" for a long time. From my understanding, all the remaining packages that were listed below surfshark, wouldn't have been installed, correct (I do not think that Update Manager installs packages in parallel)? In this case, why isn't Upgrade Manager reporting them as installable packages?

if you do sudo apt list --installed | grep package it will tell you if it's installed or not, if you did a sudo apt remove instead of sudo apt purge you might have some orphan packages installed in that case you need to run sudo apt autoremove
